# Is it possible to use controller in live agent pre chat form

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

My live agent is working fine.

1. But i want to add captcta in live agent pre chat form. But i am not using controller for live agent, so is it possible ?

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. One of my friend had similar requirement, he logged a case with support and were came to know tht its not feasible.

Comment: Is this still the situtation in 2017? I am using a controller to return a recordTypeId.
**<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseRecordTypeId" value="{!InboundRecordTypeId}" />**
However, I still need to retrieve the exact Opportunity (provided by client using addCustomDetail(Id) and then route the chat to the correct skill based on the opportunity's type/name/subject

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea from this article (https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/salesforce-live-agent-review-customization/)
I mean that you can try to create VF page with form where submit button will not submit form but will execute some javascript code within which you can use @RemoteActions to contact with appropriate controller. After all javascript logic form will be submitted by executing
`document.forms["yourFormName"].submit();`
command.

Hope this helps.